# C: how to build up a binary integer

Tags: c

I have some logic that I would like to store as an integer. I have 30 "positions" that can be either yes or no and I would like to represent this as an integer. As I am looping through these positions what would be the easiest way to store this information as an integer?

Comment: Do you want to store 30 values in one integer? I would use uint32_t for that with | and &.

Comment: My C coding knowledge is very poor. Also I am very new to working with bits in my code. Could you elaborate just a little?

Comment: Can you justify the coding / maintenance headaches associated with packing this data into an integer, vs. the saving in memory usage? If you can, I'd say look at littleadv's suggestion (bitfields) which have the advantage of getting the compiler to do the heavy lifting: if not, why not use an array of integers or enums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a 32 bit uint:

```
uint32_t flags = 0;
flags |= UINT32_C(1) << x; // set x'th bit from right
flags &= ~(UINT32_C(1) << x); // unset x'th bit from right
if (flags & UINT32_C(1) << x) // test x'th bit from right
```

Comment: +1, but you should ensure that your flag values on the right are unsigned and have the necessary width. Easiest (but a bit ugly) is to use something like `UINT32_C(1) << x`.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt isn't that done automatically? Anyway, I would define a macro like `SET_BIT(x, y) do { x |= UINT32_C(1) << y; } while(0)` to make it less ugly.

Comment: No this is not automatic. `1` is of type `int`. The day that `X` is such that you shift into the sign bit you are in trouble. So at least you should use `1U`. Also, unlikely but `int` could only be 16 bit wide. I'd make a macro just for the expression `UINT32_C(1) << x`.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct{
    int flag0:1;
    int flag1:1;
    ...
    int flag31:1;
} myFlags;
```

Using `:x` in definition of an integer `struct` member means bitfield with x bits assigned.

You can access each struct member as usual, but the values can only be according to the size in bits (in my example - either 1 or 0 because only 1 bit is available), and the compiler will enforce it. The struct will be (probably, depends on the compiler settings) packed to a total size of integers needed to represent the total bits.

Another option would be using a `int` and bitwise operators `&` and `|` to access specific bits. In this case you have to make sure yourself that setting one bit won't affect another, and that there are no overflows etc.

Comment: +1: at least bitfields mean the compiler does the heavy lifting of bit manipulation, and let's you use 1-, 2-, 3-, ...N-bit-wide fields as you wish.

Comment: Yup - another +1 for using bitfields - much clearer than the nasty |~&^<<>> bit-twiddling operators.

Comment: A bitfield for 30 flags? You will curse it once you want to loop through them or want to use them with indexed table-based approaches -- because you can't and will end with switch-case cascades.

Comment: @Secure - I'm sorry, but what part of my answer is incorrect? If you think that having flags in bitfields is not convenient you can always use integers and bit operations. I mentioned this option. Why did you downvote? For flags, specifically, you'd better use bitfields. There's no point looping through flags (if you're using them correctly), nor there's a need for switches. A flag is either on or off. If you loop through your flags - these are no longer flags.

Comment: @littleadv: There's nothing wrong with your answer, and I didn't downvote it. As for the loops and switches, such variables usually don't stand for themselves within an application. Just to give some keywords: Debugging dumps, logging, read/write from/to a config, GUI dialog, serialization for network transfer, unit tests, etc. Not to think about changing/extending it later. I find the amount of 30 flags too much for a bit field, because each has to be handled separately each time you need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #define POSITION_A 1
 #define POSITION_B 2

 unsigned int position = 0;
 // set a position
 position |= POSITION_A;
 // clear a position
 position &= = ~(POSITION_A);
```

Comment: I have seen so many people use pre-processor directives to define constants that I wonder how much they have been abused. I thought it was better to define constants using `enum` and to use pre-processor ones only for things related to architecture of the computer, linking etc...basically compile time stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as WTP's comment, you could save all your data in one unsigned int (uint32_t), and access it with AND(&), OR(|), NOT(~).

If saving storage is not a primary concern, however, I recommend not to use this compact technique.

1. You may need to expand your code to support more than 2 types(yes/no) of answers such as (yes/no/maybe).
2. You may have more than 30 questions which does not fit into one unsigned int.

If I were you, I'll use some array/list of small int (short or char) to store the values. It's  somewhat waste of storage, but much easier to read, and much easier to add more features.